# Angular material nav-bar is not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material design and currently working on navigation. I tried the examples on the official website but the navbar was not rendering. I also tried to search for the solution but non of them helped.
Here is the code:

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>    
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="navBardemoBasicUsage">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
                <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">Page One</md-nav-item>
                <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page2')" name="page2">Page Two</md-nav-item>
                <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page3')" name="page3">Page Three</md-nav-item>
            </md-nav-bar>
        <span>{{currentNavItem}}</span>
        </md-content>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        (function() {
            'use strict';

            angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
                .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

            function AppCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have clue what can be wrong with this code?

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VjgEmw?editors=1010#0. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @camden_kid No errors in the console. Did you also try it as normal web page (putting the code into html file and trying it in the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Angular Material files you are loading don't work for some reason. Updating them does work.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc5/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>    
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="navBardemoBasicUsage">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
                <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">Page One</md-nav-item>
                <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page2')" name="page2">Page Two</md-nav-item>
                <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page3')" name="page3">Page Three</md-nav-item>
            </md-nav-bar>
        <span>{{currentNavItem}}</span>
        </md-content>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc5/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        (function() {
            'use strict';

            angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
                .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

            function AppCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not able to fetch rc5 angular material design libs (js and css file). I also tried rc4 and it fetched the files but the result was the same - the problem did not resolve.

Comment: @mark When you say "it is not able to fetch rc5 angular material design libs (js and css file)", what do you mean? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, I see this kind of error:GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc5/angular-material.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
```

add this script

Here I have a link http://codepen.io/team/MHENewTech/pres/LZpzwX